# Finding an unkown parameter in a matrix so that it has non zero null space

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume that I have a matrix $C \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, which is also a sparse matrix whose elements are in the form of $C_{i,j} = e^{i2\pi p(\dots)}$. I would like to find the values of p that give non-zero null space for $C$ (i.e. $Cx=0$, with given p). I tried to obtain rref form to find a solution to the parameter but the size of the matrix can get large at times. My question is, would it be possible to use SVD to find p values that satisfy the non-zero null space condition? If not, can you recommend me ways to tackle this problem?